# How to display (or write to file) Greek characters?

Tags: c#, .net, string

How to display (or write to file) Greek characters using C#? I need to type the Greek character *epsilon* in Excel using C#. The string to be written also has English characters.
For example:

[image]

Comment: Do it like this comment `θωερτψυιοπασδφγηςκλζχξωβνμ`

Comment: Show the code you use to write to Excel.

Comment: @CodeCaster Got the answer. Edited the question title to suit the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can literally type the characters in your code. You can mix-and-match characters from any alphabet. So English and Greek characters in a single string is not a problem. If you don't know how to input them (e.g. if you don't have a Greek keyboard), then you can copy-and-paste them.

```
Console.Write("α");         // Greek lower-case alpha
```

Here is a list of lower-case and upper-case Greek characters for you to copy from:

```
α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω
Α Β Γ Δ Ε Ζ Η Θ Ι Κ Λ Μ Ν Ξ Ο Π Ρ Σ Τ Υ Φ Χ Ψ Ω
```

If you're not using Visual Studio, you need to ensure that your text editor saves the code as Unicode (UTF-8).

---

Alternatively, you can use [Unicode escape codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa664669(v=vs.85)) to write Greek characters.

```
Console.Write("\u03B1");    // Greek lower-case alpha
```

It is `\u` followed by the four-digit hexadecimal number of the character you want. You can find the hexadecimal values in [this table](https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/ancient/greek/greekchart/). Simply ignore the `&#x` part.

Comment: Thanks Works perfectly. Good explanation too  to boot. :)